# PHP readline produces scandir

Tags: php, command-line-interface, readline

I've noticed strange behavior from readline while using it for user input from a CLI.

When I press multiple tabs it prints a scandir to the input stream.

Below is the code:

```
$msg = "";
while ($msg != "quit")
{
    while (($msg == "") || ($msg == "\r"))
        $msg = readline ("> ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is behavior from your shell. You will get the same result without running the PHP script. At the prompt, type  `>` and tab twice.

You can prevent this by registering a no-op completion with [readline_completion_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline-completion-function.php).

```php
<?php
$msg = "";
readline_completion_function(function ()
{
    return [];
});
while ($msg != "quit")
{
    while (($msg == "") || ($msg == "\r"))
    {
        $msg = readline("> ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and didn't get the same behavior from the CLI. Correction, it did.

Comment: I do. This is not PHP behavior.

Comment: Ok, guess next step is to figure out how to get around the behavior.

Comment: The term for others is .. Command Line Completion ..

Comment: You can prevent this by registering a no-op completion function, see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

To stop this behavior, register an auto complete function that returns no matches to auto complete.

```
function dontAutoComplete ($input, $index)
{ return ([]); }

readline_completion_function ("dontAutoComplete");
```